# IComparer is not used in LINQ expressions

Tags: c#, linq, networking, concurrency, locking

I'm seeing some weird behavior and not able to figure out how it can occur. I have 2 sorted sets which I am using a buffers to reorder TCP packets by sequence number, and I am reading packets out of these sets within a lock statement.

Here is a simplified example:

```
SortedSet<Packet> in = new SortedSet<TcpPacket>(new SeqComparer()); // inbound buffer
SortedSet<Packet> out = new SortedSet<TcpPacket>(new SeqComparer()); // outbound buffer

public void BufferPacket(Packet packet) {
    // Some code which does not modify buffers
    bool buffer = isOutbound ? out : in;
    lock (buffer) {
        buffer.Add(packet);

        Packet bufferedPacket;
        // Removing retransmitted packets
        while (buffer.Count > 0 && (bufferedPacket = buffer.Min()).SeqNum < expected) {
            buffer.Remove(bufferedPacket);
        }

        // Process buffer
        while (buffer.Count > 0 && (bufferedPacket = buffer.Min()).SeqNum == expected) {
            buffer.Remove(bufferedPacket);
            expected += bufferedPacket.Length;
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

And something is causing this exception:

```
System.ArgumentException: At least one object must implement IComparable.
   at System.Collections.Comparer.Compare(Object a, Object b)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Min[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
```

which seems to imply that after checking `Count > 0`, `Min()` found no objects. I am very confused as to how this could happen while locked.

Comment: `lock` does not lock the collection / set, it stops other threads entering the following statement. If you have somewhere else could modify `buffer` which does not use the same `lock`, the collection / set can still be modified.

Comment: Can you share the signature of `Packet`? It must implement `IComparable` in order to use `Min`.

Comment: sorry, my sample actually left out that I have passed a comparer to SortedSet to compare the packet's seqnum. The code works fine most of the time, but randomly encounters this failure.

Comment: @weichch, I have double  checked and these sets are private, and only modified within this function (after assigning the ref to the buffer var). From my understanding of locks, this should be fine. `BufferPacket` can be called from multiple threads, but there should only be 2 threads executing this code concurrently (1 thread for in and 1 thread for out)

Comment: `Min` is a LINQ method, it does not use `Comparer` you passed into `SortedSet`. `Min` does not compare objects when there are only 0 to 1 objects in the set. And if the set contains 2 or more items, then `Min` compares `Packet` and you will get exception like that. Can you verify that when this code works, how many items are in the set?

Comment: I think you got it. Most of the time there is just 1 packet in the buffer (except for rare cases of out-of-order packets which is what I am trying to solve with this buffer.

Comment: Because the set is ordered, so you don't really need `Min`, you can use `First()` or `Last()` depending on how your comparer compares.

Comment: I you want to post an official answer, I will accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This is answer extracted from comments below the question*

This is **not** a lock related issue.

As per the comments, OP implemented `IComparer<Packet>` and passed it into `SortedSet<Packet>`. The comparer whilst it is used by the collection, `Min` method being a LINQ extension does not use it.

Instead, `Min` expects the `Packet` class to implement `IComparable`. And because the class does not seem to have implemented the interface, the exception is thrown.

`Min` does not compare objects when collection only contains 0 or 1 items. When the collection contains 2 or more items, `Min` compares `Packet` and the exception is thrown.

As per the OP's comment, this is where the confusion was:

> Most of the time there is just 1 packet in the buffer (except for rare cases of out-of-order packets which is what I am trying to solve with this buffer. )

The error message however might also be misleading in this scenario:

> At least one object must implement IComparable.

*It implies there might be no items in the set.*

To fix this issue, because the sets are already ordered, using `First` or `Last` as per the implementation of `IComparer<Packet>` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the [`Enumerable.Min`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.min) extension method of the LINQ library, use the [`SortedSet.Min`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sortedset-1.min) property instead:

> Gets the minimum value in the `SortedSet<T>`, as defined by the comparer.